# Blank 'Grub Boot Menu' when changing boot options

Tags: ubuntu, boot, grub, boot-loader, mate-desktop

I was having the issue of a black screen on Ubuntu restart and startup. It seems like my monitor is somehow disconnected when I start Ubuntu because I get 'No Signal Detected'.

I started following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it) guide on how to fix it but whenever I change anything in the Grub Boot Menu like `nomodeset` then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>  or <kbd>F10</kbd>  to boot, it just goes to this screen:

[image: Frozen Grub Boot Menu]

Then stays like this. Doesn't respond to any keys.

The only way to boot is to turn off the computer when the monitor turns off then turn the computer back on, getting to the following screen and selecting 'Ubuntu'.

[image: countdown].

I even tried reinstalling and have the same issue.

Can anyone help?

Comment: did you try a `sudo update-grub` in a terminal? maybe your `grub.cfg` file is corrupted or sth

Comment: @Moonstroke Just tried that, no luck.

Comment: how old is your hard disk?  You say that rebooting sometimes works, so my first guess is that your disk is dying (or the data or power cable is loose), which is sometimes preventing grub from loading its boot menu.  Otherwise, my second guess is that it could be faulty RAM or some other hardware fault - can you boot reliably on a USB stick or CD-ROM?

Comment: @cas It's not old, it's a Crucial M4 SSD. Yes I can reliably boot from USB. Rebooting only works when forcing turning off then on again, added details to post.

Comment: Look very carefully at your hard disk activity light when you boot. Is it flickering after you see the black screen appear? With SSDs the load time is so short that it's harder to use this method to test what's going on, but it may still give you some idea. Also check your partition filled percentage, make sure home / root are not full, just as one more test to confirm. Use df -hT. Your issue rings a faint bell but I can't remember what the cause was.

Comment: On initial grub boot options, go into grub edit mode, and delete the 'quiet splash' item from your default kernel, then start the boot process. You're just guessing where it is failing, with some luck, this will show you where it's failing, unless the failure comes before the console text starts to display. This is by the way why I'd never use a boot splash, it hides exactly the information you need to see, with no benefit at all to anyone.

Comment: @Lizardx Thanks, removing 'quiet splash' allowed me to restart and boot, although just seeing text. I removed it from `/etc/default/grub` too. Not ideal but it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing 'quiet splash' from the boot options allowed me to restart and boot, although now I'm just seeing text when entering my encryption password, not the nice Ubuntu Mate screen. I removed it from `/etc/default/grub` then did `sudo update-grub` too. Not ideal but it works.

Comment: In the future when you post an issue for help, please do not leave out the critical information that would point people to the solution, in your case, Mate desktop plus Encryption. These are both relatively non standard for a user desktop, and would have saved you some debugging time. Particularly encryption plus mate. Those two together introduce a solid set of possible failure points. As an alternate test, I'd also recommend trying a different desktop and display manager and see if the issue is in mate, the encryption password step, or both together.

Comment: @Lizardx I included Mate as a tag but yeah, I should have included the encryption too. Not going to reinstall my OS again just to try to find the issue though, as that's what I'd need to do to replicate it.

Comment: I mentioned this combination in particular because there's a much higher level of complexity with two relatively uncommon things running together: mate + encryption login. The pool of possible people to catch bugs in that scenario grows quite small, and your personal odds of finding one grow correspondingly large. In general reinstalls are a poor solution since you don't really learn why the issue is happening. I would guess that mate is failing to talk to the relevant encryption tool and nobody has yet noticed this fact, or fixed it. Could be mdm itself. Small projects have finite manhours.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I understand reinstalls are a poor solution which is why I made the thread and persevered with the OS since I like Ubuntu Mate. I'm pretty much out of ideas of what to try now though if I want to get the Ubuntu Mate encryption screen back, not something I'm desperate for but due to the lack of replies, seems like not many people have had this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you done an fsck? I know that seems crazy but it's really not out of the ordinary for an SSD to fail even fresh out of the box.

Comment: How do I run this and on which partition?